# How do I bind multiple fields to one TextBlock in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my current code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strain}"  />
    <TextBlock Text="/"  />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaximumStrain}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

What I would like to do is have one TextBlock with the expression "{Strain}/{MaximumStrain}"

Comment: P.S. I don't literally need a TextBlock. Another control that is visually similar will work as well.

Comment: Just a quick thought. Could bind it to a list/collection and use converter?

Comment: Hard to pick a winner. Both answers have their advantages and limitations.

Comment: Nice one. This question should be quite useful for many now. Thanks Jonathan for pointing out pros and cons of each method :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you could use the "Run" command, try this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{Binding Strain}"></Run>
            <Run Text="/"></Run>
            <Run Text="{Binding MaximumStrain}"></Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

---

Pros: Can change font settings for each `Run`.

To avoid adding an empty space between your text all you have to do is place the Run commands in the same line like this:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Strain}"></Run><Run Text="/"></Run><Run Text="{Binding MaximumStrain}"></Run>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use Multibinding with stringformat.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}/{1}">
            <Binding Path="Strain" />
            <Binding Path="MaximumStrain" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

---

Pros: Direct control over spacing.

Cons:

- No complex font styling.
- Needs `Mode=OneWay` in some cases. May throw an error or silently fail to bind depending on the use case.